# WPF Value Converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a WPF application and I need a value convertor with more than 1 binding path, is that possible?

It works with 1 path so far:

`Binding="{Binding Path=Price, Converter={StaticResource vPriceConvertor}}"`

I wanna give the `Price` and the `discount` to the converter so he can calculate the `endprice`.

Comment: Further to @Dennis' point, you're spreading the business logic into the UI layer... this is an antipattern...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Value converters are intended... for value conversion. That's why they're value *converters*.

To do what you want, you should make a property `EndPrice` in view model, and calculate its value in view model. Why are you trying to bring a non-UI logic into UI??

Comment: I thought it was better to calculate the endprice everytime but adding a property in view model seem the best idea, thx.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) class. For example:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock" DataContext="{StaticResource myViewModel}">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource vPriceConvertor}"
                  ConverterParameter="myParameter">
      <Binding Path="Price"/>
      <Binding Path="Discount"/>
      <!-- Insert other paths here -->
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Implement [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) instead of IValueConverter to actually do the conversion, since it supports multiple sources.

Answer (score 1):

Parys -

You could always create a collection (in View Model) which contains Price and Discount and then pass it through your XAML (through IValueConverter).

But to re-iterate @Dennis and everybody else point - then your converter will have calculation logic - which is not recommended.